# Docker Run Command - Why does "docker run <image ID> echo 'foo'" work, but /bin/sh -c echo 'foo' doesn't? They should be equivalent

Tags: docker

With a default entrypoint of `/bin/sh -c`, I'd expect to see `docker run <image ID> echo 'foo'` result in `/bin/sh -c echo 'foo'` execute which does not print foo (foo is an arg for sh here, not echo).

However, it seems to run as if its quoted/passed in as a single arg to sh. What is the reason for this?

The only reason I can think of is that docker run command(s) are parsed as a single command and handed to `/bin/sh -c` as a single item

Comment: It's not accurate to say that the default ENTRYPOINT is `/bin/sh -c`. According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), "If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the <command> will execute in /bin/sh -c". That implies the entire value of `CMD` (or whatever you pass on the command line) is provided as a single argument to `sh -c`.

Comment: Your supposition that Docker misrepresents what it's doing is completely accurate. It's not alone in that, though; most `ps` implementations have the exact same bug when printing command lines.

Comment: Awesome, these answer my question. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The `sh -c` option takes a single argument, which is parsed and executed as a shell command.  If that command has multiple words, you need to quote it so it gets passed as a single argument.

This isn't Docker-specific and you can see it in a local shell:

```sh
$ echo 'foo'
foo
$ /bin/sh -c echo 'foo'

$ /bin/sh -c "echo 'foo'"
foo
```

If there are additional parameters, the `sh -c` command can see them as positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

```sh
$ sh -c 'echo "$2"' foo bar baz quux
baz
```

In a more Docker-specific context, you can see the same behavior using this as a `docker run` command

```sh
$ docker run --rm busybox sh -c 'echo "$2"' foo bar baz
baz
```

In a Dockerfile, RUN, CMD, and ENTRYPOINT will automatically add the `sh -c` wrapper so you don't need to explicitly specify it.

```sh
# same:
CMD ls && exec main_program
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "ls && exec main_program"]

# unnecessary extra sh -c:
CMD sh -c 'ls && exec main_program'
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "main_program"] # without redirects, environment variables, ...
```

You only need the explicit `sh -c` if you have a complex command as a `docker run` or Compose `command:` override command.

Comment: My question was specifically around what (and how) things are passed to your ENTRYPOINT. In the example of echo "foo" you'd expect to only see a newline printed, but when its handed to a docker run command, you see its passed as a single argument and prints foo. Just looking to understand why was all.

Comment: If you `docker run ... /bin/sh -c echo 'foo'`, your host's shell will parse that command into four words, and (if the image declares an ENTRYPOINT) the entrypoint will be invoked with those four words as parameters.